# Node - middleware not applying a req property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my project, when a user logs in, I generate an auth token like so:

```
// For my User model
userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = () => { 
  const token = jwt.sign({ _id: this._id }, config.get('jwtPrivateKey'))
  return token
}
```

I then apply an auth middleware on a route that allows a user to create posts.

auth middleware:

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.header('x-auth-token')
    if (!token) return res.status(401).send('No token provided')

    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtPrivateKey'))
        req.user = decoded
        next()
    }
    catch (ex) {
        res.status(400).send('Invalid token')
    }
}
```

My route:

```
router.post('/', auth, upload.single('postImage'), async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.user._id)
    const post = new Post({
        postImage: `http://localhost:3000/${req.file.path}`,
        caption: req.body.caption,
        user: req.user._id
    })

    await post.save()
    res.send(post)
})
```

As you can see, I log the req.user._id in the route, and when I call this endpoint, I get `undefined` logged to the console. Instead I expect the `_id` of the user who generated the auth token.

Below is my login route, where a user gets their auth token.

Login route:

```
router.post('/', validateLogin, async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) return res.status(422).send(errors.array())

    let user = await User.findOne({ $or: [{ username: req.body.usernameEmail }, { email: req.body.usernameEmail }]})
    if (!user) return res.status(400).send('Invalid username/email or password')

    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
    if (!validPassword) return res.status(400).send('Invalid username/email or password')

    const token = user.generateAuthToken()
    res.send(token)
})
```

Does anybody know the issue here? Thanks.

Comment: What is the source of your POST?  Is it coming from a submitted form in the browser?  Are you sure that the `x-auth-token` custom header is added to that POST request?

Comment: If you put a `console.log(req.user)` right after this line `req.user = decoded`, what does it show when you do the POST.